# How can I convert a dictionary-like string to a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary like string as below:

```
str = "Access AR1:\n\tTargets: \n\t\tManagement Name:csw_1\n\t\tObject Name:csw_obj_1\n\t\tdetails:103\n\t\tManagement Name:csw_123\n\t\tObject Name:csw_obj_134\n\t\tdetails:123\n\tSources: \n\t\tIP:10.20.30.40\n\t\tSubnet Mask:255.255.255.255\nAccess AR2:\n\tTargets: \n\t\tManagement Name:csw_2\n\t\tObject Name:csw_obj_2\n\t\tdetails:110\n\t\tManagement Name:csw_431\n\t\tObject Name:csw_obj_21\n\t\tdetails:134\n\tSources: \n\t\tIP:10.20.10.10\n\t\tSubnet Mask:255.255.255.192"
```

and this goes on in the same format, which would look like:

```
Access AR1:
    Targets: 
            Management Name:csw_1
            Object Name:csw_obj_1
            details:103
            Management Name:csw_123
            Object Name:csw_obj_134
            details:123
    Sources: 
            IP:10.20.30.40
            Subnet Mask:255.255.255.255
Access AR2:
    Targets: 
            Management Name:csw_2
            Object Name:csw_obj_2
            details:110
            Management Name:csw_431
            Object Name:csw_obj_21
            details:134
    Sources: 
            IP:10.20.10.10
            Subnet Mask:255.255.255.192
```

and this need to be changed to:

```
str = {"Access AR1": { "Targets": [{"Management Name:csw_1", "Object Name":"csw_obj_1", "details":"103"}, {"Management Name:csw_123", "Object Name":"csw_obj_134", "details":"123"}]
                      "Sources": {"IP":"10.20.30.40", "Subnet Mask": "255.255.255.255"}
                    },
      "Access AR2": { "Targets": [{"Management Name:csw_2", "Object Name":"csw_obj_2", "details":"110"}, {"Management Name:csw_431", "Object Name":"csw_obj_21", "details":"133"}]
                      "Sources": {"IP":"10.20.10.10", "Subnet Mask": "255.255.255.192"}
                    }
      }
```

I tried `ast.literal_eval, eval` and ended up with an error.

Comment: Can you please share the code you're intended to convert the string to a dictionary and the error?

Comment: @DiesanRomero i used, ast.literal_eval(str), it throws Syntax error as in the given string space and quotes are missing

Comment: To use **ast.literal_eval** the string need to be inside of parentheses. What this method does is evaluate a string as if it were a Python expression. If you want to convert that string into a dictionary, I can give you some options. By the way, just curious where this string comes from and why it is using that format?

Comment: "Sources":"IP":"10.20.30.40" this can t be dict .correct this line and then I can give you code that make the output from the input

Comment: @BahaeElHmimdi its mistake, edited now

Comment: @DiesanRomero even i am confused about who designed this kind of API response, apart from all, i have to access each value so i need to process it to dictionary to fetch the values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your string is nearly yaml - replace the \t with one or more spaces and it loads as YAML.

First:

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Then this code works:

```
import yaml
import pprint

str = "Access AR1:\n\tTargets: \n\t\tManagement Name:csw_1\n\t\tObject Name:csw_obj_1\n\t\tdetails:103\n\tSources: \n\t\tIP:10.20.30.40\n\t\tSubnet Mask:255.255.255.255\nAccess AR2:\n\tTargets: \n\t\tManagement Name:csw_2\n\t\tObject Name:csw_obj_2\n\t\tdetails:110\n\tSources: \n\t\tIP:10.20.10.10\n\t\tSubnet Mask:255.255.255.192"

str1 = str.replace( '\t', '    ' )

res = yaml.load(str1)

pprint.pprint( res )
```

Output:

```
{'Access AR1': {'Sources': 'IP:10.20.30.40 Subnet Mask:255.255.255.255',
                'Targets': 'Management Name:csw_1 Object Name:csw_obj_1 '
                           'details:103'},
 'Access AR2': {'Sources': 'IP:10.20.10.10 Subnet Mask:255.255.255.192',
                'Targets': 'Management Name:csw_2 Object Name:csw_obj_2 '
                           'details:110'}}
```

Or, if you really want this as a string then:

```
str = repr(res)
```

**UPDATE**

Just realised that e.g. 'Managent Name:csw_1' isn't being detected as a key:value. Needed a regex `re.sub()` to split these onto separate lines to fix this:

```
import yaml
import pprint
import re

str = "Access AR1:\n\tTargets: \n\t\tManagement Name:csw_1\n\t\tObject Name:csw_obj_1\n\t\tdetails:103\n\tSources: \n\t\tIP:10.20.30.40\n\t\tSubnet Mask:255.255.255.255\nAccess AR2:\n\tTargets: \n\t\tManagement Name:csw_2\n\t\tObject Name:csw_obj_2\n\t\tdetails:110\n\tSources: \n\t\tIP:10.20.10.10\n\t\tSubnet Mask:255.255.255.192"

# replace \t with four-space indent
str1 = str.replace( '\t', '    ' )

# further tweak to split sub-keys like " Management Name:csw_1" onto separate lines
str1 = re.sub(r"^(\s+)(.*?\S:)(\S.*)", r"\1\2\n\1    \3",str1,flags=re.MULTILINE )
   
res = yaml.load(str1)

pprint.pprint( res )
```

This is the string after tweaks:

```
Access AR1:
    Targets:
        Management Name:
            csw_1
        Object Name:
            csw_obj_1
        details:
            103
    Sources:
        IP:
            10.20.30.40
        Subnet Mask:
            255.255.255.255
Access AR2:
    Targets:
        Management Name:
            csw_2
        Object Name:
            csw_obj_2
        details:
            110
    Sources:
        IP:
            10.20.10.10
        Subnet Mask:
            255.255.255.192
```

Result:

```
{'Access AR1': {'Sources': {'IP': '10.20.30.40',
                            'Subnet Mask': '255.255.255.255'},
                'Targets': {'Management Name': 'csw_1',
                            'Object Name': 'csw_obj_1',
                            'details': 103}},
 'Access AR2': {'Sources': {'IP': '10.20.10.10',
                            'Subnet Mask': '255.255.255.192'},
                'Targets': {'Management Name': 'csw_2',
                            'Object Name': 'csw_obj_2',
                            'details': 110}}}
```

Comment: (+1) I don't know but I was figting with `yaml.safe_load(StringIO(s.replace('\t', '\s\s\s\s')))` for long time but could not figure out, `str.replace( '\t', '    ' )` seems great 

Comment: That has a sense for me, and I was looking out where the string is coming from .

Comment: i struggled to regex replace string to dict string(adding quotes and brackets), without luck

Comment: Error -- "yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here" in res = yaml.load(str1)

Comment: Code and data above works for me using Python 3.9.5 on Win10

Comment: @nonuser yaml strictly depend on indent. so check your tabs count.

Comment: @barny works now, but still data are not well formatted, like 'Subnet Mask' is splited and  "Subnet" became value of earlier key, only "Mask" became the key of respective value

Comment: @barny the updated solution suites and worked without any issues

Answer (score 2):

Hello this is the solution you need

```
strr = "Access AR1:\n\tTargets: \n\t\tManagement Name:csw_1\n\t\tObject Name:csw_obj_1\n\t\tdetails:103\n\tSources: \n\t\tIP:10.20.30.40\n\t\tSubnet Mask:255.255.255.255\nAccess AR2:\n\tTargets: \n\t\tManagement Name:csw_2\n\t\tObject Name:csw_obj_2\n\t\tdetails:110\n\tSources: \n\t\tIP:10.20.10.10\n\t\tSubnet Mask:255.255.255.192"
nvstr=strr.replace("\n\t\t","-").replace("\n\t","+")
#print(nvstr)
nvdd={}
for u in nvstr.split("\n"):
   #print(u) 
   dts=u.split("+") 
   
   nvdd[dts[0]]={}
   
   for el in dts[1:]:
       
     dts1=el.split("-")
     nvdd[dts[0]][dts1[0][:-1]]={}
     for el1 in dts1[1:]:
         
       k,v=el1.split(":")
       nvdd[dts[0]][dts1[0][:-1]][k]=v
       
print(nvdd)
```

Comment: Thanks ```k,v=el1.split(":")``` some error, btw, solution suggested above have worked good enough

Comment: this method probably works, but is not extensible. what if the input has more than 3 levels?

Comment: you wanna  extensible solution?

Comment: yes. extensiblility is one aspect of software design, right? i'm not the OP, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to convert the input to a dictionary, without having to make any adjustments to the string itself beforehand:

```
import re
s = "Access AR1:\n\tTargets: \n\t\tManagement Name:csw_1\n\t\tObject Name:csw_obj_1\n\t\tdetails:103\n\tSources: \n\t\tIP:10.20.30.40\n\t\tSubnet Mask:255.255.255.255\nAccess AR2:\n\tTargets: \n\t\tManagement Name:csw_2\n\t\tObject Name:csw_obj_2\n\t\tdetails:110\n\tSources: \n\t\tIP:10.20.10.10\n\t\tSubnet Mask:255.255.255.192"
def to_dict(d):
   k, v, r = None, [], {}
   for *b, a in d:
     if not b:
        if k is not None:
           if not v:
              r[j[0]] = (j:=re.split(':\s*', k))[-1]
           else:
              r[re.split(':\s*', k)[0]] = to_dict(v)
        k, v = a, []
     else:
         v.append([*b[1:], a])
   if k is not None:
       if not v:
          r[j[0]] = (j:=re.split(':\s*', k))[-1]
       else:
          r[re.split(':\s*', k)[0]] = to_dict(v)
   return r
```

---

```
import json       
new_s = [re.findall('\t|[^\t]+$', i) for i in s.split('\n')]
print(json.dumps(to_dict(new_s), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "Access AR1": {
        "Targets": {
            "Management Name": "csw_1",
            "Object Name": "csw_obj_1",
            "details": "103"
        },
        "Sources": {
            "IP": "10.20.30.40",
            "Subnet Mask": "255.255.255.255"
        }
    },
    "Access AR2": {
        "Targets": {
            "Management Name": "csw_2",
            "Object Name": "csw_obj_2",
            "details": "110"
        },
        "Sources": {
            "IP": "10.20.10.10",
            "Subnet Mask": "255.255.255.192"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m sure your code works but personally I find it incomprehensible; I’d appreciate some comments to explain what’s going on. And better variable names; e.g. `d` doesn’t mean anything helpful, neither does `a` or `b` or `v`